# Invoke function for each enumarable item while mapping with Automapper

Tags: .net-core, automapper

I have 2 classes:

```
class A
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

class ADto
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public bool Flag { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to map IEnumerable to IEnumerable which I perform with `_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ADto>>(aList)` but the issue is that I would like calculate what should be the value of the `ADto.Flag` for each entry that is being mapped.

I **don't** want to configure mapping **globally** but define callback when performing this particular mapping.

Can I set the value of that flag during mapping?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Comment: Can `Flag` be deduced from `MyProperty`? Or you wish to set the same value at the moment of mapping for the whole collection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you're setting up AutoMapper, you'll need to add a [custom projection](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Projection.html#)
. This will specify how to map from `A` to `ADto`.

```csharp
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
  cfg.CreateMap<A, ADto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Flag, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => { /* DO MAPPING HERE */ }))
```

Here's a .NET Fiddle demonstrating how to use it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7IJF6z

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue because it will apply the callback globally, I want to specify it during mapping.

Comment: The only other way I see to do it is by [passing in context](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper) during the `Map` call, e.g.

`mapper.Map<A, ADto>(src, opt => opt.Items["otherStuff"] = otherStuff);`

Then your global mapper can act on context specific to that mapping. The purpose of AutoMapper is to keep mapping logic out of your domain or business logic, so it might not be a good fit for this use case if the mapping logic is highly context specific.